# Returning a single element from an iterator block - Iterator cannot contain return statement

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, iterator, yield

Let's say I have the following method. In some came

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(UserLoginCommand command)
    {
        User user = userRepository.Get(u => u.Email == command.UserEmail);
        if(user != null)
        {
            if(!user.Activated)
            {
                return new IEnumerable<ValidationResult>() {new ValidationResult("NotActived", Resources.UserNotActivated)};
            }

            if(user.IsPasswordIncorrent)
            {

                yield return new ValidationResult("IncorrectPassword", Resources.IncorrentPassword);

            }

        }
    }
```

The actual situation is actually a bit more complex but I've left a lot out for illustration purposes.

The point is in some cases, I want to iterator to continue collecting multiple errors...but in other cases there is a fatal error and I only want to return a single error but it will not let me:

```
Iterator cannot contain return statement
```

What should I do?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty explicit.  You can't mix `yield` and `return`, as the function execution is deferred until the iterator is called upon.  I'd suggest getting rid of the `yield` and just building your own enumeration.  I'm hoping Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert will chime in here on exactly why the compiler can't handle this case though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to return a collection of size one, you can do this:

```
if(!user.Activated)
{
  yield return new ValidationResult("NotActived", Resources.UserNotActivated);
  yield break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the simple solution I needed.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated by the error message, you can't mix `yield return` statements and `return` statements into a single method.

You have two general approaches:

1. The method should be eagerly evaluated; you should use all `return` statements, find a way to convert all `yield` statements into returns.
2. The method should use deferred execution, find a way to turn all `return` statements into `yield` statements.

In your case, it's probably #2, but in other situations either may be appropriate.

Now, how to turn a `yield` into a `return`:

wrap the single element into a collection of some sort and return that:

```
return new[]{ someItemToReturn };
```

or

```
return Enumerable.Repeat<T>(someItemToReturn, 1);
```

Now, how to turn a `return` into a `yield`:

```
foreach(var item in collectionYouWereReturning)
    yield return item;
```

You can use `yield break;` to indicate that the sequence has ended even if the method has not reached it's natural end.  Note that `yield break;` should be pretty rarely used.  Using it a lot would be code smell (but this does seem like a case where it would be appropriate).

Now, ideally, we'd have a `yield foreach` keyword of some sort so that you could yield a collection inside of an iterator block, but as of yet no such keyword has been added to the language.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I learned a few useful things that will be useful in the future but in this case I preferred to keep the same pattern I used everywhere (yield return) but just return a single element in exceptional cases. Paul Phillips answer was simple and worked. Upvote for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't that return statement actually be a yield?

```
yield return ValidationResult("NotActived", Resources.UserNotActivated);
```

If you really need to return a collection, you can `yield return` a collection, too (like you have it), it's just not necessary since you have only one.

Also, in the case that you want to stop enumerating explicitly, you can use `yield break;`