# C# Iterator can not contain return statement

Tags: c#, data-structures, struct, ienumerable, ienumerator

I'm trying implement python like range data struct in c# witch implements `IEnumerable<int>`.

My `Range` struct has 3 integer fields: `start, stop, step`.

I also write `RangeIterator` data struct which implements `IEnumerator<int>` and accepts range object to it's constructor. Because I want to decouple *range iterator* object and range object.

And in `Range` struct I write:

```
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new RangeIterator(ref this);
    }
```

Everything works fine.

But there is some cases which range should not be generate number due to `start, stop, step` parameters. And I want to check if it should generate number(s) before creating `RangeIterator` object for optimization.

I changed code to:

```
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (!ShouldGenerate)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            return new RangeIterator(ref this);
        }
```

But it says

> Iterator can not contain return statement

How can I avoid creating `RangeIterator` in this situation?

I'm sorry, English is not my native language.

Edit 1:

I found error reason in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23391246/4791963) but I haven't any idea how to avoid creating enumerator object if it isn't needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 'Iterator cannot contain return statement ' when calling a method that returns using a yield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391119/error-iterator-cannot-contain-return-statement-when-calling-a-method-that-ret)

Comment: Thanks, I found error reason, but not problem solving.

Comment: Have you seen `Enumerable.Range(int, int)` and `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`?  You can look at how these are implemented by reading the reference source.

Comment: Thank You. I solve with `Enumerable.Empty<int>().GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why the `ref` parameter for `RangeIterator` constructor? I just can't see what purpose that could possibly serve.

Comment: to avoid copying range object (its value type). And RangeIterator doesnt changes range object members, only reads. Thus I needn't duplicate range object and dont use additional stack memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found error reason in this answer but I haven't any idea how to avoid creating enumerator object if it isn't needed.

You can't avoid enumerator object because returning `null` is not allowed. But you can avoid unnecessary enumerator object allocation by using static **singleton** instance (since the empty enumerator is immutable by definition). For instance, using the one returned from `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` like this

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (!ShouldGenerate)
        return Enumerable.Empty<int>().GetEnumerator();
    return new RangeIterator(ref this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something similar to this:

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
   return (ShouldGenerate) ? new RangeIterator(ref this) : new RangeIterator(); // an empty iterator
}
```

Comment: i don't think so... but generating a zero-based-sized iterator merely affect performance :)